# EC2 instance putty re-used keypair not recognised

Tags: amazon-ec2

First up it's nearly impossible to identify if this is a duplicate or not given the generic nature of the displayed error. This is potentially a very specific and niche scenario. Please do not falsely mark this as duplicate. It's sad that I have to type this :(

I have 2 ec2 ubuntu instances. The first one created 6 months ago and working perfectly.

I created a second ubuntu instance this morning and told it to use the same keypair as the existing instance. They're in the same zones(?) but different base vpc. I selected it from the list so I presume it should be visible to both vpc's. From what I could see that should be ok.

Both are ubuntu so the user is "ubuntu". Both are using the same key pair. I merely cloned my saved putty config and changed the public IP before attempting to connect however i'm getting the *"PuTTY Fatal Error: Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey) OK:* error.

Unless i'm mistaken the same .ppk should work for both instances, that's the entire purpose of keypairs. The only thing I can presume is that AWS failed to associate the key pair with the new instance.

**What are the likely reasons for this happening?**
AWS documentation https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/linux-credentials-error/
Says to check the username "ubuntu" and key pair name which are both correct.

**I'm going to blow the instance away and start again but it would be nice to be able to know what AWS is doing wrong so I can avoid the issue in the future.**

Update: New instance... I imported a different pub key and used that and the problem persists when I try and connect with it's associated ppk.

Comment: Experiencing this now, can you share what resolution worked for you at the end?

Comment: @clusterBuddy I answered my own question. The Ubuntu Image AWS was offering for the instance was bad. They had 2 Ubuntu images. When I tried the other one it worked fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was the AWS Amazon Machine Image (AMI) I was using. I was using the latest ubuntu??. When I switched to the other ubuntu it worked fine.

[image]